# X graphical environment broken after kernel update on 18.04

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, kernel

After executing the ubuntu updates as already performed many times the X graphical environment does not boot anymore.

The latest update installed kernel 4.15.0.48 in grub.
When selecting an older kernel in grub 4.15.0.47 the machine boots correctly in X.
I am using nvidia legacy drivers:nvidia-utils-390 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Which should be the latest. 
How can this be resolved?

Comment: How have you installed the Nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I installed it via repository ppa:graphics-drivers if I remember correctly.

However I tried a manual upgrade to nvidia drivers version 418 and this solved my issue.

FYI: I notice now in my Software & Updates screen that ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-driver/... is present but not checked. 
Is this the reason why an automatic upgrade of the package is not suggested?